# Why does the CSS look different on my Angular2 dev server and production build?

Tags: css, angular, sass, webpack, font-awesome

**EDIT**
I Noticed this problem only occurs in Chrome

I'm using Angular2 with Webpack and I have a problem where some SCSS styles look a little bit different in my dev environment, compared to my production build.

In these screenshots I will show the top right corner of my navbar, where I have a user icon. As you will see the icon is positioned correctly on my dev server but wrongly in the production build

**User icon on DEV, positioned centered correctly:**

[image]

**User icon on PROD, wrong position:**

[image]

In Chromes dev tools, we can see the blue highlighting of the user icon, that they do indeed take up different amounts of space, **despite the CSS being  exactly the same**:

**DEV**
[image]

**PROD**
[image]

Comment: Can you check the 'Height' property in the 'Computed' tab. And check where it gets it's height from.

Comment: The height is 32 px on prod, 45 on dev, in the computed tab, and the height property itself is "disabled" so it's automatically calculated somehow

Comment: @ErazerBrecht, I just discovered the production build renders it correctly on Firefox. It's only in Chrome where it renders it wrong, and only on the production build.

Comment: Do you have some minification in the production build, which removes all the spaces in the HTML?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Yes I do actually. Could that be the culprit? However, I solved the problem switching over to a flexbox based grid.

Comment: If your elements have `display: inline-block` and spaces in between the elements, the space character will be displayed too (in the font-size of the element). This might be your problem. See [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Answer (score -2):

This issue should be due to caching by the dev server.

Try restarting the dev server and refresh the browser.

Comment: Did not help the problem